# I am trying to split a list based on binary condition

Tags: python

```
list [['0.jpg',0],['1.jpg',1],['2.jpg',1],['3.jpg',0],['4.jpg',1]]
```

I am trying to split it into two list

the output I am expecting to have is two list:

```
list_0 = [['0.jpg',0],['3.jpg',0]]
list_1 = [['1.jpg',1],['2.jpg',1],['4.jpg',1]]
```

Comment: yes you are right, i just fixed  the list, i forgot to the first key in ' ' .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not appropriate you name your variable `list` because it's a python built-in function:
What this code is doing is that, the for loops will loop the original list to see if the second item of every sub-list matches a condition then it should include that sub-list to a new list.

```py
original_list = [['0.jpg',0],['1.jpg',1],['2.jpg',1],['3.jpg',0],['4.jpg',1]]

list_0 = [i for i in original_list if i[1] == 0]
list_1 = [i for i in original_list if i[1] == 1]

print(list_0)
print(list_1)
```

---

```
[['0.jpg', 0], ['3.jpg', 0]]
[['1.jpg', 1], ['2.jpg', 1], ['4.jpg', 1]]
```