# Seperate images into two folders based a binary condition from a list

Tags: python, machine-learning

I have a few images in one folder called all_images, the images named as 0.jpg, 1.jpg, etc.
I have a list,
list= [['0.jpg',0], ['1.jpg',1], ['2.jpg',1], ['3.jpg',0], ['4.jpg',1]]

I want to separate the images based on their labels,
so, the images who have label (0) I want to store them in folder called 0_folder
then the images who have label (1) I want to store them in folder called 1_folder

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am trying to split a list based on binary condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75199955/i-am-trying-to-split-a-list-based-on-binary-condition)

Comment: You forgot to post a minimally reproducible example of the issue you're facing

Comment: I am not familiar how to split the images from one folder into two folders based on each image label in the list, could you please help ?

Comment: Hi Matt2918! I recommend you to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve this question.

Comment: Original folder has images (0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg), I want to copy the images from original folder to another folder based on a condition from the list, if the image in list has label 0, store the image in folder called 0_folder, if the image has label 1 store the image in 1_folder.

Comment: Can you help me Jamiu? :)

Answer (score 0):

this easy for loop would separate your images.
All thats needed now is the code to store the items.

```
for item in list:
    if item[1]==0:
        print("this has the value 0",item)
        # "write your code here"
    elif item[1]==1:
        print("this has the value 1",item)
        # "write your code here"
```

Comment: i want to create 2 folders, each folder has the images based on its label 0 or 1

Comment: Original folder has images (0.jpg, 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg, 4.jpg), I want to copy the images from original folder to another folder based on a condition from the list, if the image in list has label 0, store the image in folder called 0_folder, if the image has label 1 store the image in 1_folder.

Comment: the problem i couldn't figure out how to store them tetris programming